# How to find type of pointer

Tags: c++

I have a optional property `event` that I define as a pointer in this struct:

```
struct AnimatedSprite {
    //...some other properties
    Event *event;
};
```

Let's say I want to store a StartTransitionEvent , defined like this:

```
class Event {
public:
    Event() = default;
};

class StartTransitionEvent: public Event {
public:
    int test = 1;
};
```

I can create and assign the StartTransitionEvent:

```
auto sprite = AnimatedSprite{};
auto newEvent = StartTransitionEvent{};
sprite.event = &newEvent;
```

But how do I get the type once I need to call something like:

```
eventBus->EmitEvent<StartTransitionEvent>(sprite->event);
```

Should I do some sort of checking on my `event` pointer to get to the StartTransitionEvent? Or maybe not use pointers at all and go for a `std::variant` to store the event with all it's possible child-classes?

Comment: Maybe use something like `eventBus->EmitEvent(sprite->event)`. Whether this is valid depends on the details of your `eventBus` design and implementation. Maybe post some more code? To see which stuff is polymorphic in your code and which is not.

Comment: You may be looking for [dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

Comment: With the shown `Event` class you can't receive the derived type of the object. The information is not stored anywhere. You need to make `Event` polymorphic by giving it at least one `virtual` function, then `dynamic_cast` can be used or better you define a `virtual` function interface, so that you don't actually need to query the type, but let virtual dispatch handle the polymorphism.

Comment: Also, if you want `AnimatedSprite` to _own_ the `Event`, then there is a problem since you are giving it a pointer to a local variable which it can't own. Instead you would need to give `Event` a `virtual` destructor, then replace the `Event*` with a `std::unique_ptr<Event>` and create the event with `std::make_unique<StartTransitionEvent>()` instead of declaring it as a variable.

Comment: If you need to inspect the concrete type of a object at run-time you're doing it wrong. If you have a member of `EventBus` called `EmitEvent(...)`  it sounds like you need a virtual member of `Event` called `Emit()` (possibly passed the EventBus or some other target) and an override of that member in `StartTransitionEvent` that emits a StartTransitionEvent. The whole notion of polymorphic dispatch is that you don't need to handle the concrete underlying type of the object at the point of dispatch. It can quickly become an over engineered `switch(type)` statement.

Comment: @user17732522 I made a virtual destructor, but it won't let me assign a `std::unique_ptr<StartTransitionEvent>` to a `std::unique_ptr<Event>`

Comment: @Oli It does allow it, but `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable, so you might be trying to copy it where you have to `std::move` it. Or avoid this problem entirely, by not saving the result in an intermediate variable: `sprite.event = std::make_unique<StartTransitionEvent>();`.

Comment: I've tried the virtual destructor / std::move approach and the adding of Emit() to the event, but everywhere I run into trouble..here's the EventBus class I'm using: https://pastebin.com/mkJTZj92

Answer (score 1):

You could use double dispatch, a.k.a. visitor pattern and let the specific Event visit the EventBus.

So something like

```cpp
class Event
{
public:
    virtual void Emit(EventBus& eventBus) = 0;
};

class StartTransitionEvent : public Event
{
public:
    void Emit(EventBus& eventBus) override
    {
        eventBus.EmitEvent(this);
    }
};

sprite.event.Emit(eventBus);
```

Comment: @pptaszni actually no. In the original example it said "sprite->event" as a parameter to EmitEvent. And the event property in the AnimatedSprite struct was of type Event*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're designing such a hierarchy, your `EventBus` class should be able to work with the base `Event` class. You achieve that through virtual functions in the `Event` class:

```cpp
struct Event {
  Event() = default;
  virtual ~Event() = default;

  virtual void action1(); // event-specific actions
  virtual void action2(); 
  virtual void action3(); 
};

struct StartTransitionEvent : Event {
  void action3() override; // override some actions 
};

struct EventBus {
  void emit(Event& event) {
    // ...
    event.action1();
    // ...
    event.action2();
    // ...
    event.action3();
  }
};

int main() {
  StartTransitionEvent event;
  EventBus bus;
  bus.emit(event);
}
```